# Signing Configs are not applied

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle

I have signingConfigs config which should enable v1 v2 v3 v4 signature in gradle but it doesn't apply.

```
    signingConfigs {
    release {
        v1SigningEnabled true
        v2SigningEnabled true
        enableV3Signing = true
        enableV4Signing = true
        keyAlias '*********'
        keyPassword '*********'
        storeFile file('*********')
        storePassword '*********'
    }
}

    flavorDimensions "test"
productFlavors {
    staging {
        dimension "test"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    dev {
        dimension "test"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

when I build apk file and run

```
   apksigner verify --verbose .apk
```

i get this message :

```
    Verifies
Verified using v1 scheme (JAR signing): false
Verified using v2 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v2): true
Verified using v3 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v3): false
Verified using v4 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v4): false
Verified for SourceStamp: false
Number of signers: 1
```

why can this happen? Thanks

Comment: What version of AGP and build-tools are you using? Signing with all four schemes works fine for me with the latest version